# I'm trying to add an external library to a Source mod, and I'm having some trouble

Tags: c++, header-files, steam

I'm trying to add [this Serial Communications library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992/Serial-library-for-C) to the Source SDK code to try to integrate my own serial input into Steam games.  I've got the example projects on the Serial library I downloaded working fine.  I added the Serial project to the Source solution and gave the "Server (HL2)" project a dependency to it (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express).  I then went to my .cpp file under the Server (HL2) project and simply added

```
#include "Serial.h"
#define STRICT
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

which are the headers defined in the example project that was working for me, and got a lot of errors when I went to compile.  The errors are all along the lines of:

```
\serial.h(190): error C2065: 'CE_RXOVER' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(191): error C2065: 'CE_RXPARITY' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(193): error C2065: 'CE_TXFULL' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(215): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCTSTR'
\serial.h(220): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Open'
\serial.h(220): error C2433: 'CSerial::LONG' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
\serial.h(220): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
\serial.h(220): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPCTSTR'
\serial.h(220): warning C4183: 'Open': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
\serial.h(223): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Close'
\serial.h(223): error C2433: 'CSerial::LONG' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
\serial.h(223): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
\serial.h(223): warning C4183: 'Close': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
\serial.h(241): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Setup'
\serial.h(241): error C2433: 'CSerial::LONG' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
\serial.h(241): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
\serial.h(244): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
\serial.h(244): warning C4183: 'Setup': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
\serial.h(250): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'SetEventChar'
\serial.h(250): error C2433: 'CSerial::LONG' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
```

They repeat and then...

```
\serial.h(361): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'LPOVERLAPPED'
\serial.h(329): error C2065: 'm_lLastError' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(345): error C2065: 'DCBlength' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(345): error C2065: 'DCB' : undeclared identifier
\serial.h(345): error C2070: 'unknown-type': illegal sizeof operand
```

There's also a whole lot more "undeclared identifiers" where that came from.  I feel like there's a very obvious solution somewhere, either the way I have the solution set up or the linker or something.  But it finds the file, it's just not interpreting it correctly it seems.  When I take out

```
#include "Serial.h"
```

It compiles fine, so it has something to do with the way I'm adding that new header file.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn´t about the linker, but the compiler. Either your missing some `#include`, or this library is crap.

Comment: @deviantfan To test it out, I imported my test project and Serial project into the overall solution, linked them, and it compiles fine.  It's when I try to link the existing project to the new Serial header where it's not working.

It seems to be something with the existing "Server (HL2)" dealing with the header in the right way.

Comment: I had to update the projects from Visual Studio 6 to 2013.  Could something have messed up in that transition?

Comment: Yes yes yes. Don´t even try to migrate some non-trivial stuff. Take the pure code files, make a new project, and import them. (Note1: The lib is from 2003. and maybe written specifically to run in VS6. If so, chances are not bad that a better C++ compiler (=anything, just not VS6 or TurboC++) will reject to compile it anyways, independent of what you do.). (If proper language support is important to you, forget VS. All versions. Now in 2015, they´re still struggling with things they should have done 1999)